# pam_mount not executing on Ubuntu LTS 22.04

Tags: upgrade, mount, 22.04

I recently upgrade from 20.04LTS to 22.04LTS. In my setup I used pam_mount to mount various external drives on a NAS when the user logs in. This was working perfectly fine in 20.04 and it still does work on two computers that upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04.
However I have one additional Laptop that I setup from scratch. I moved the pam_mount.conf.xml file to /etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml. In that file I have the path to lsuserconf just as on the other to working devices.

I checked the pam_mount manpage and confirmed that I followed everything as described. However pam_mount does not seem to be executed on that new laptop at all. Checking dmesg and journalctl there is no trace from pam_mount at all.
Additional the service description seems to be missing in /etc/pam.d/service completely.

I have read that that 22.04 uses the new "ADsys" client. I guess it has to do with the fact that I joined the domain in my home network setup differently on this new laptop. I used the UI dialog during the initial setup. I know about the option to get a license for Adsys and to setup login scripts. However I would really prefer to stick to pam_mount as this is the way it works on the two other upgraded computers that work fine.

How can I make pam_mount work on that laptop?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my problem today.
When comparing the installed packages on the working and none working device, I figured out that fresh installation from 22.04LTS did not have "**libpam-mount**" and "**libpam-mount-bin**". So I installed them both and everything works like a charm now!

You can easily check if the package is missing by using

```
dpkg -l | grep libpam
```

This will list all libpam packages. **libpam-mount** and **libpam-mount-bin** should be there if you want the pam module to mount your user specific shares on login.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your ***/etc/pam.d/common-auth*** file has the following line at the bottom:

```
auth  optional  pam_mount.so
```

AND the ***/etc/pam.d/common-session*** file should have this line at the bottom of it:

```
session  optional  pam_mount.so
```

If those lines are not present the pam_mount module is likely not going to load for you upon login. Those lines should be automatically added when you run:

```
sudo apt install -y libpam-mount cifs-utils
```

[EDIT] I know that the OP solved on their own, but I'm posting to bring a little more clarity to the solution.